# Android: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError for a native c++ library in an Android app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, abi

I have a C++ library built into my Android app. Most of the time it works fine, and I could never reproduce the problem myself, but sometimes, rather rarely, the app crashes in production with this exception, visible in Firebase Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/package.name-xxx==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/package.name-xxx==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libJniMyMissingLibrary.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
       at com.jni.missing.LibraryHolder.<clinit>(LibraryHolder.java:12)
```

I get several crashes per week, it is a small but steady percentage of users.

This is how I load the library, nothing special:

```
public class LibraryHolder {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("JniMyMissingLibrary");
    }
```

I've started recently to log `getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName())`, for the past several crashes it returned `com.google.android.packageinstaller` or `null`.

`Build.MANUFACTURER` logged `LGE` and `Google` in a couple of latest crashes.

Happens on different Android versions (8.1.0, 11, 10), various devices (Nexus, Pixel), all not rooted, according to Firebase.

I am also logging the path to the native library dir:

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES)
                       .nativeLibraryDir;
```

I see values such as `/data/app/package.name==/lib/arm64`, `.../lib/arm`, or `.../lib/x86`. There are 0 files in this folder.

In production I'm not using `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` or `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false` which, as far as I understand, would 'unpack' the .so file into the folder. I've played with these params locally, I see the file in the folder, the app works; but since I can't reproduce the problem, I have no idea if this would help to solve the problem in production (should I try?).

I've checked [this article](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis). I'm not using `abiFilters` because it says that without this filter, all ABIs would be included (which is what I want).

I distribute the app as an app bundle, just one file `app-release.aab`. If I unpack the bundle, I see the `libJniMyMissingLibrary.so` files in 4 folders: `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64`. This matches the article's list of supported ABIs; but the `nativeLibraryDir` path seems to be different sometimes?.. I don't know if it should be 100% matching though.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that I don't see any pattern as to what architecture, smartphone model, or any other param that can cause this.

I can't reproduce the problem on my devices or in emulators. Without the c++ library, the app won't work, I can't just have a "workaround" for when the library is missing. But it should be there, shouldn't it?..

Why is it missing and how do I ensure it is in place?

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if any more info is needed.